# MySQL InnoDB lock row

Tags: mysql, innodb

I work with mySQL InnoDB Table. 
Mysql database queries with php script. 
When A user select a record in specific table I'd like to lock this and allow only read process for other user. 
So I try to use

```
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE NAME = 'Jones' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

So my question is when user B try to select the same record how to know that the record is locked and when user A try to update record how to authorize this operation.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB row locks are only intended for temporary use during a transaction (e.g, when you want to temporarily hold up anyone else who's trying to look at or modify the row). If you want to allow users of your application to "lock" records, row locking isn't suited for this purpose. Instead, do it at the application level: create a column in the table to represent which of your users has locked the record.